# Admin panel ignores URL path

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes

I have deployed WordPress on Kubernetes using Bitnami's WordPress chart.
I wanted to host WordPress under a specific path, not on root.
To achieve that, I did the following:

- modified `wp-config.php` file:

```php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/wordpress/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress/' );
```

- created Ingress resource to expose WordPress for public access:

```yaml
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: '404'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /wordpress(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: wordpress-svc
              servicePort: http
```

I am able to access example.com/wordpress - I see the default WordPress site:

[image]

However, when I go to the Admin panel (I click the WordPress logo at the top), I am taken there, and the URL changes to "example.com/wp-admin/about.php" - normally, it should be "example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/about.php".

Even though the panel displays properly:

[image]

When I click on any item on the left, I am taken to the wrong site.   For example, clicking on "Users" takes me to "example.com/wp-admin/users.php". I get 404. However, if I modify the URL manually and change it to "example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/users.php", the correct page loads (but the URL in my browser again changes to the wrong one, without "WordPress".

What's the cause of that?
I don't see any 30x in the Network tab of DevTools, so I assume that it's some JavaScript of WordPress that modifies my address bar. How do I stop that?

One more observation - when I click on the default "Hello world" post that WordPress creates by default, it takes me to the correct URL.  Only the admin panel seems to not work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to move the contents of `/opts/bitnami/wordpress` to `/opts/bitnami/wordpress/wordpress` and to remove entirely the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation from the ingress.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured the ingress that way will will remove the Wordpress from the path itself

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: '404'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /wordpress(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: wordpress-svc
              servicePort: HTTP
```

You can simply try

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: '404'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /wordpress(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: wordpress-svc
              servicePort: http
```

annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

which is removing the path WordPress from your ingress or URL

You can also take reference of my WordPress YAML files : https://github.com/harsh4870/Kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx/blob/master/ingress.yaml

Comment: I tried to change `rewrite-target` to `/`. This way I am not able to navigate anywhere outside of the main page of my WordPress site. It makes sense, because if I try to go to any path under WordPress (like /wp-admin/...) it will rewrite the request to "/", so WordPress will always return main page.